# Does gatling use Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate on every request?

Tags: encoding, gatling

After executing some performance using gatling, i have noticed more bandwidth results than expected on the server side.
I think/thought galitng encoding (gzig, deflate) by default on every request, but now I am not sure about that.
By activating the logging (to see what request headers are sent), the "Accept-Encoding" header is not displayed.

Answer (score 1):

> I think/thought Gatling encoding (gzig, deflate) by default on every request, but now I am not sure about that.

Why would that be? No, it's not, that's something you have to specify, for example as a [default header](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/http/protocol/#header) on the HTTP protocol.